# wp-config.php already exists for WordPress (Docker, ECS)

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, amazon-ecs

I am running WordPress inside a container and hosting it on ECS. The database is RDS.

Everytime I build a new docker container and deploy to ECS it requires a fresh install. Then it says wp-config.php already exists.

I am tempted to copy the wp-config.php populated with the database configuration into the container but that is not a good practice.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's definitely not best practice to do the configuration manually over and over again, either ;)

To have persistent data with docker, you can either use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) or [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). In both cases the data is directly stored on the backing file system, **not** using the overlay / union file system, that is used for containers.

`Volumes` are handled by the docker engine, `bind mounts` are directly mapped to where you specified. If you are using docker compose, your `docker-compose.yml` would look like

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  your_service:
  image: your_image
  volumes:
   # bind mount example
   - type: bind
     source: /path/on/host
     target: /path/inside/container
   # volume example
   - type: volume
     source: your_volume
     target: /path/inside/container
 [...]
 volumes:
   your-volume:
```

The equivalent commands for `docker run` can be found on [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) . For example

```
docker run --volume=[host-src:]container-dest[:<options>] ...
```